# How to multiLine an #import

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this long `#import` in my C++ header file:

```
#import "XXX.tlb" no_namespace rename("A", "B") rename("C", "D") and so on
```

How can I beautify it so it would look something like this:

```
#import "XXX.tlb" 
        no_namespace 
        rename("A", "B")
        rename("C", "D") 
        rename("E", "F") 
        ...
```

Comment: #import ain't in the C++ standard. Do please add some more tags.

Comment: Doesn't the normal line continuation with backslash work?

Comment: @molbdnilo with "\n"? if that's the case, then no.

Comment: @RayOldProf No, with just a backslash at the end of each line.

Comment: @molbdnilo no :( the compiler dont like it.

Comment: @RayOldProf Really? [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) suggests otherwise (scroll all the way down). Did you perhaps leave some whitespace between the backslash and the line break?

Comment: @molbdnilo You are absolutely right. i was writing "\" instead of simply \. Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backslash to escape newlines, as you would for any preprocessor directive.

There's an example at the bottom of [the Microsoft documentation for `#import`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
#import "test.lib" no_namespace \
   rename("OldName", "NewName")
```

Applied to your example, that's:

```
#import "XXX.tlb" \
    no_namespace \
    rename("A", "B") \
    rename("C", "D") \
    rename("E", "F") \
    ...
```

Be sure not to leave a space after the backslash, otherwise all you'll be doing is escaping the space!